# Convert text string (1st/2nd etc) into dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to try to convert a basic string i.e. `1st, 2nd, 3rd` into a date formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy` where the `mm/yyyy` part are this current month and year and the day equals the "number" in the cell.

For example

Cell K5 contains the string "1st"
Formula in cell A5 takes K5 and converts to 01/11/2019

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to strip the last two characters:

```
 =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2))
```

Then format as desired.  Mine is `mm/dd/yyyy`

[image]

Comment: Cheers Scott, youre amazing as always

Comment: But won't these values change if the workbook is opened again in December?

Comment: @Andreas yes it will, to stop that simply copy paste over the value, or use vba.

Comment: copy paste *values*

Comment: I have a convert to text button on the sheet that finalises the sheet before moving onto the next month. Months are seperated into seperate sheets

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this:
If so, you have to remove letters from selection then excel will convert them into date. For clarity, remove letters, then convert cells to date format.

[image]

Comment: @Andreas 119 years not 1019 years, but the comment is correct, this does not return what is wanted.